# Few questions related to Atlas HiveMetastoreBridge code

Tags: apache, metadata, hive-metastore, apache-atlas

I was going through HiveMetastoreBridge code in Apache Atlas and encountered few doubts.Pardon me if these questions are very naive.

[HiveMetastoreBridge code](https://github.com/apache/atlas/blob/master/addons/hive-bridge/src/main/java/org/apache/atlas/hive/bridge/HiveMetaStoreBridge.java)

1. Why are we clearing relationships in findEntity method?
2. What does add referred entity does exactly in the background ? To be clear in toTableEntity method we are adding ObjectId of related entites as attributes as well calling addReferredEntity method of AtlasEntity.
3. In registerInstance method why are we creating references from first entity to other referred entities in else if statement. When will multiple entities be created and why will the first have reference to others?
4. In importTable method why after creating AtlasEntity processInst we are again creating AtlasEntitiesWithExtInfo createTableProcess and adding process entity and path entity to it? Why not Table entity too?